# In AS3 how can I post a string to php with out url encoding the string?

Tags: actionscript-3, post, base64, urlencode

Is there a way to post to a php page without url encoding the string?  I have read about urldecode in php, but I need to keep the + symbols and I think urldecode will strip them out.

Comment: using using URLVariables "/9j/4AA+S" becomes %2F9j%2F4AA%2BS".

Comment: base64 is what I am trying to pass, so I may be chasing a red herring with this.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem completely... If you send data via GET to a PHP script (e.g. `site.com?string=hello%20world`) and use that data in the script the encoded characters will be converted back to original form i.e. `hello world`.

Comment: Agree with Marty there shouldn't be an issue here the data is being URL encoded because it's being passed in a URL this should automatically be decoded when you read it back on the php side, the two hex characters after the percent sign represent the hexadecimal value for the ASCII value encoded, certain symbols are reserved for special meaning in URLs or are otherwise excluded http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Haven't you guys even read the question? He wants to POST, NOT GET. @smilinfoo are you posting it through a url variable? or are you sending it without name?